# Storyboard for all screen size

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

There is possible to add storyboard for any screen size?
Example if the iPhone is 6 plus load storyboard 1 if is iPhone 5 load storyboard 2.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible, although I would not recommend it. In fact I would **strongly** recommend against it.

It is a lot more work to develop in the first place, is a lot more error-prone, and is also a lot more work to test and maintain, and makes it possible to have platform-specific bugs when you have different configurations for each screen size.

With the size classes added in iOS 8 Apple has made dealing with different sized displays easier and cleaner. They are pushing developers away from separate storyboards for iPhone and iPad and towards a single storyboard that manages all platforms.

Comment: A little bit off topic, the concept is the same with an app with 2 or more languages?

Comment: So what is the best way to match app for all screen size?

Comment: @user1569766 read this documentation : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Read the documentation?!? Are you mad??

Comment: Use size classes + auto layout. It should solve all your localization problems if used correctly. Everything is 1000 times easier with stack views.

Answer (score 0):

Try having one storyboard with a universal path then splitting the path using segues based on the phone you are using.  I made a cocoapod for screen sizes that might be useful for you.

[Here's a tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vc0KjFlMPeQ)